# iPad Scrolling to Top of iframe

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, scroll, mobile-safari

I did my best to recreate this in something accessible.
I've got an ipad mini running ios7 and am using something similar to this:

```
<div id="holder">
    <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.cnn.com" id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>

#holder {
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/khJgY/4/

Now the issue is, scrolling in the iframe works fine. But if you change focus (say to one of the other HTML/CSS/JS edit boxes) the iframe scrolls back to the top left and I have no idea why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following CSS fixed it for me. 
([source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3838289))

On the inner iframe:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem myself. I found out that is a bug where certain  CSS makes the browser jump to the top of the page, but only in certain situations, like in forms and iframes. For me, I found out that applying a box-shadow when a button was active made this happen. To fix it, I just made the effect not trigger on smaller screens by setting box-shadow: none;.

Comment: For me, removing anything that affected the height of the container, as well as box-shadow solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the following css fixed it for me:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```